# Powershell: Remove-Item - path throwing error at integers

Tags: powershell

This is a relatively short one but cannot seem to figure out how the computer is able to see this differently. I have a folder I want to delete with Powershell but the `Remove-Item` function is throwing an error because the path contains `Program Files (x86)`.

See below code:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {Remove-Item -Path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Test -Force -Verbose}`

It doesn't like the fact that the program files has brackets around the x86. When I put quotation marks around the path it doesn't recognise it at all.

How can I get around this?

Error even when using single quotes:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Test' -Force -Verbose}`

`Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Test' because it does not exist. + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...test:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand + PSComputerName        : MKC-03812`

Comment: Are you sure the folder still exists? Sounds like the `Remove-Item` was successful.

Comment: I agree with @BoogaRoo. Go look if ```test``` still exists.

Answer (score 1):

This might help some
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2

but the answer is

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Test' -Force -Verbose}
```

Comment: When I put it in quotation marks it cannot find it for some reason. Will have a look into it more though and read the link you sent - thank you

Comment: @mcgirlja if what I wrote doesn't work then post the error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is using double quotes. Use single quotes to stop the interpretation of the parenthesis as its own clause/statement.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Test' -Force -Verbose}
```

Also, if your commands contains complex or nested quoting, you may have more luck using the `-LiteralPath` parameter instead.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {Remove-Item -LiteralPath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Test' -Force -Verbose}
```